# Laravel : Keyword 'create' added to above <!DOCTYPE html> as well as command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, command-line

I have build a laravel project where there is keyword called 'create' been added to the above of every page as well as in command prompt. 
In every page of my application a keyword called 'create' in the above section and in command prompt also. suppose i want to run `php artisan migrate`, the command start with create and then migration file created same as for every command i run means it starts with `create`.

But while i run the same command in other projects nothing happened everything run smoothly.

I know the problem is weird but if anyone face the problem before hope help me to find it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because create keyword is added accidentally in some file. Once i  faced this issue, accidentally a keyword was mistyped in routes.php before

Comment: Thanks I also did the same mistake. accidentally i also put `create` inside a `routes.php`

Answer (score 0):

You have most likely accidentally added the word 'create' to a file somewhere in your application, probably outside a PHP tag.

I recommend doing a source code search for the word.